# Basic Linked List singly

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

My doubt is when I am making b=c.next,it means b will point to Node d. But when I start printing from the head node, it gives answer as 5,6,7,8. Why is my line b=c.next not executed. The answer must be 5,8 right?

```
class Node:
def __init__(self, data):   # data -> value stored in node
    self.data = data
    self.next = None


a=Node(5)
b=Node(6)
c=Node(7)
d=Node(8)
a.next=b 
a.next.next=c 
a.next.next.next=d
b=c.next 
print(a.data,b.data,c.data)
while a is not None:
    print(a.data)
    a=a.next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line `b=c.next` is getting executed. If you were to write:

```
while b is not None:
    print (b.data)
    b=b.next
```

You would see the output `6 8`. It prints `b.data` and then `b.next.data` (which is the same as `d.data`).

References don't work quite the way you think they do. When you create the initial nodes, you have essentially this (`=>` here means "refers to"):

```
a => Node5
b => Node6
c => Node7
d => Node8
```

Those assignments create new nodes, and make the variables refer to those nodes. But `a`,`b`,`c`, and `d` are *references* to nodes, not the nodes themselves.

When you assign `next` references:

```
Node5.next => Node6
Node6.next => Node7
Node7.next => Node8
```

You're changing what those nodes refer to.

Finally, you change `b`, creating:

```
b => Node8
```

When you assign to `b`, you're telling `b`, "instead of referring to `Node6`, start referring to `Node8`." But `Node5.next` is still referring to `Node6`.

If you want to change the order so that it goes `5,8`, you'd have to write:

```
a.next = c.next
```

Another way to look at it is to create one node and two references, like this:

```
a = Node(5)
b = a
```

Now, obviously, `a.data` and `b.data` will both be 5. And if you write `b.data = 6`, then `a.data` will also be 6 because `a` and `b` are referring to the same thing.

But what happens if you then write `b = Node(12)`? Now what you've done is created a new node and made `b` refer to it. *But `a` is still referring to the node with value 6.* So, `a.data = 6` and `b.data = 12`.

Changing what `b` refers to doesn't change what `a` refers to.

Comment: Python *doesn't have pointers*. I think speaking about pointers in the context of Python is almost always going to be misleading/confusing to beginners, unless you are carefully explaining how python variables *sort of* act like pointers to someone that comes from, say, a heavy C background.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I see your point. I changed the discussion to say "references," and added some clarification. Better?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I see a lot of confusion around the term pointers among beginner python programmers. Remeber, Python is now the major teaching language in many University programs, so there are a lot of first-time coders on this tag in particular. Otherwise, your explanation was spot-on.